# Cannot Set Min and Max for Datpicker in Java Android

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

Stuck on how to set up a minimum and maximum date with the DatePicker, so for instance the user can't set the date pass the current date. Similarly the user won't be able select a date before 1960, so far I've been able to set up the DatePicker my code is below:

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        EditText mEdit;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        public void selectDate(View view) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
        }
        public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
            mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            mEdit.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
        }
        public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
            }

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
                populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In **DatePickerDialog** there is two method for setting the **min** and **max date** which takes **input time** as **milliseconds**

[Min Date of Picker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29)

[Max Date of Picker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate%28long%29)

So the code will be like

```
DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
DatePicker dp = d.getDatePicker();
dp.setMaxDate(maxDate);
dp.setMinDate(minDate);
return d;
```

But this method is available in **API Level 11**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below.

```
public class DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange extends DatePickerDialog {

 static int maxYear=2014;  // max date which you want to set
 static int maxMonth=11;
 static int maxDay=31;

 int minYear=1960;        // min date which you want to set
 int minMonth=0;
 int minDay=1;


public DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange(Context context,  OnDateSetListener callBack,int minYear,int minMonth,int minDay,int maxYear,int maxMonth,int maxDay) {
    super(context,callBack, maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
    this.minDay = minDay;
    this.minMonth = minMonth;
    this.minYear = minYear;
    DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange.maxDay = maxDay;
    DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange.maxMonth = maxMonth;
    DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange.maxYear = maxYear;
}

@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    super.onDateChanged(view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        if (year > maxYear ||monthOfYear > maxMonth && year == maxYear||
                 dayOfMonth > maxDay && year == maxYear && monthOfYear == maxMonth){
            view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
            }else if(year < minYear ||monthOfYear < minMonth && year == minYear||
                 dayOfMonth < minDay && year == minYear && monthOfYear == minMonth){
             view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay );
            }
     }
}
```